# Add (Math) 1 to a field populated via a random number function

Tags: javascript, html

coding novice here. I am simply trying to add 1 to a field which has been populated by a 1 to 10 random number generator via a button click.

```
<form name="Random Num">
<input type="button" value="Generate Number" onclick="randInt();" />
<input type="button" value="Lets add 1 to that" onclick="plusOne();" />
</br>
    <input type="text" id="Rando" name="Rando" />
</form>
```

The generate number works fine and generates a number into the text field 'Rando'.

The second button, the 'Lets add 1' does not. Java below:

```
function Random() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
}

function randInt() {
    document.getElementById('Rando').value = Random()
}

function plusOne() {
    document.getElementById('Rando').value = + 1
}
```

I appreciate I may be missing something simple!

Many thanks
L. Nomran

Comment: What does your button actually do?

Comment: try `document.getElementById('Rando').value++`

Answer (score 0):

Your `plusOne` function is just setting the value to `1`.

Instead, you have to retrieve the value, parse it, add `1` to it, then assign the result back to the value.

```js
function Random() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
}

function randInt() {
  document.getElementById('Rando').value = Random()
}

function plusOne() {
  document.getElementById('Rando').value++;
}
```

```html
<form name="Random Num">
  <input type="button" value="Generate Number" onclick="randInt();" />
  <input type="button" value="Lets add 1 to that" onclick="plusOne();" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="Rando" name="Rando" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could see, most of your code is fine. Apart from the `plusOne` function.
To increment a number, you could use 3 approaches.

```js
 document.getElementById('Rando').value = document.getElementById('Rando').value + 1
```

This is the first approach, but it is not suggested, since it is really Verbose and makes the code look untidy

A second approach, which is just a cleaner way of doing this is

```js
 document.getElementById('Rando').value += 1
```

It takes the value, and increments is by 1. If you put some other value in place of 1, that would work as well. You could put, 2, 3 etc.. without any problems

The third approach, which is going to work only for this use case is

```js
 document.getElementById('Rando').value++
```

The reason this works in your case is that `++` is the increment by 1 operator. And since you want to increase your value by one, you can use this. This won't be effective for other positive values however.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers and explanations. .value += 1 This seems to just add a 1 to the number, so 1 changes to 11 rather than 2. The .value++ worked however for this scenario since it was just adding 1.